# Math in Safari (especially iPhone)

Tags: iphone, math, safari, mobile-safari, mathml

Is there an easy way to display math in the Safari web browser? My main target is the iPhone safari.

Comment: I suppose you can just print `1 + 2 = 3` directly. :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this blog](http://www.jem-thematic.net/en/node/1189) the webkit renders MathML combined with a certain stylesheet and xslt.

Comment: So hopefully this means that Safari on Macs also support MathML. That will make my life easier for one project.

Comment: @James The webkit doesn't support MathML. CSS is used to render it using images as far as i'm aware.

Comment: MathML support is underway in WebKit and you can see this in the project tracker and from recent activity in the source code repository.  It looks like it is in its early stages. There is a concrete goal to implement a small, initial increment of support. It will not blow you away but I think being focused on one part to start with shows there is a serious desire to achieve something concrete.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia's (mediawiki's) math rendering engine outputs simple HTML for simple math and PNGs when the math becomes more complex. The math itself is written using LaTeX, more on that [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula).

They apparently use [texvc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texvc) to render the math as PNG or HTML.

Comment: +1 - A more reliable and (I suspect) more browser compatible way than my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/).  A quick google search found [this helpful page](http://www.jem-thematic.net/en/node/1189).